# Selenium fluent wait and page factories

Tags: selenium, page-factory

So, I've been rattling my head with this challenge, so far I'm not winning.
I'd highly appreciate if anyone could assist me with this.
Details as follows.

Below is the code **Example: 1**,

1.In example 1, the incorrect xpath is this "//input[@id='identifierIdd']"

2.This is deliberate just to examine fluent wait. As expected after 1 minute test exited and with exception `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:`

```
    import com.google.common.base.Function;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
    import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES;
    import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

    public class Tester01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    webDriver.get("https://accounts.google.com/
      signin/v2/identifier? 
      continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F
      &service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn
      &flowEntry=ServiceLogin");

    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement webElement;

    Wait<WebDriver> fluentWaiter = new FluentWait<WebDriver> 
    (webDriver).withTimeout(1, MINUTES)
           .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
           .withMessage("element couldn't be found after 1 minutes")
           .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);


    webElement = fluentWaiter.until(new Function<WebDriver, 
    WebElement>()
    {
       public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
          return driver.findElement(By.xpath
            ("//input[@id='identifierIdd']"));
        }
    });

    webElement.sendKeys("testemail.com");
    }
    }
```

3. So, I've decided to experiment with fluentwait & pageFactory unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to achieve the below line from `Tester01` class with pageFactory.

`return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierIdd']"));`

4. Details for fluentwait & pageFactory experimentation.
   Below is the code **Example: 2**,

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

   public class LocatorTest{

   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using="//input[@id='identifierIdd']")
   public WebElement elementTest;

   }
   ```

And `Tester01` class with `LocatorTest` class

```
    public class Tester01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    webDriver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?                        
       continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.
       com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1
       &flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin");

    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement webElement;

    Wait<WebDriver> fluentWaiter = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(webDriver)
            .withTimeout(1, MINUTES)
            .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
            .withMessage("element couldn't be found after 1 minutes")
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    LocatorTest locatorTest = new LocatorTest();
    PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, locatorTest);

    webElement = fluentWaiter.until
    (new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
    {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return locatorTest.elementTest;
        }
    });

    webElement.sendKeys("testemail.com");
        }

    }
```

So `Tester01` class with pagefactory doesn't wait fluently for 1 min, test fails immediately with `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:`

I think I know what the issue is however doesn't really know how to overcome this issue,

This is my explanation of the issue, in **Example: 2** `Tester01` class the return statement in fluentWaiter instance doesn't use the appropriate driver instance.

This is the line I'm talking about `return locatorTest.elementTest;` because I think the method apply() accepts an `Webdriver` instance however 
the line `return locatorTest.elementTest;` doesn't utilise the `driver` instance.

Is my thinking correct? 
could someone please assist me with this issue please?
Or propose an alternative solution please?

Please let me know if any of the above doesn't make sense or need more info.

Thanks in advance
Niro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PageFactory.initElements()` will create `Proxy` for all the `WebElement` and `List<WebElement>` fields. And also setup the locator strategies that are passed in `FindBy` annotation. No location of elements is performed. It is a lazy initialization. The actual location will be done when commands like `click(), sendkeys()` etc are sent to the `webelement`.

Now in first case, you search for the actual element

```
webElement = fluentWaiter.until(new Function<WebDriver, 
    WebElement>()
    {
       public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
          return driver.findElement(By.xpath
            ("//input[@id='identifierIdd']"));
        }
    });
```

In the second case, you are just making a java call to a page object which returns you back the Proxy object. No selenium business is involved.

```
webElement = fluentWaiter.until
    (new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
    {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return locatorTest.elementTest;
        }
    });
```

But when this code is run - `webElement.sendKeys("testemail.com");`, actual element location is done and it fails. There is no wait involved here. The `PageFactory` was initialized with the `webDriver` instance.

Look at [[ExpectedConditions]](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class which you can use along with the FluentWait or the specialized [[WebDriverWait]](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html). Use a method like [visibilityOf(WebElement)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) from `ExpectedConditions` which return the `ExpectedCondition<WebElement>`.

Or you can even look at a `LocatorFactory` which waits for a certain time period while searching for an element. [AjaxElementLocatorFactory](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/AjaxElementLocatorFactory.html) and [AjaxElementLocator](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/AjaxElementLocator.html). Though this will be an overkill as these are meant for Ajax cases rather than a wrong locator.

Comment: Great many thanks for swift response.
Understood, I shall experiment with **expectedConditions** class

Gotta few follow up questions

f1. You've mentioned in the answer that actual location occurs during **click()** and **sendKeys()**

f3. So, If I create util methods for **elementToBeClickable, validityOf etc**, which will of course return the webElement and I could perform **sendKeys()** on the returned webElement. Is this recommended? 
or 
performing **sendKeys()** within those util methods is recommended?

Thanks again for help

Comment: When a fresh page is loaded, in almost all cases selenium will handle loading of elements etc etc before it returns control to the next line of code. So you wont need to use waits in majority of situations (Though one common issue is that, UI is not stable and clicks are blocked by overlaying element exception). But if there is ajax activity on loading or some element getting (in)visible  etc due to javascript dynamic stuff then sometimes wait is required. I would not recommend creating util methods for waits as it will used sparingly. It will be just more code to maintain and worry about.

Comment: Great, many thanks for the advise @grasshopper,
As you've said on the last comment, I'm struggling with a unstable UI, hence the investigation in wait mechanisms.

I'm aware of maintenance work required for these wait methods, especially for the current product i'm working on these assortment of **WAIT's** provides a lot of reliability

Comment: You should look at implicit waits if majority of elements need wait. Though be careful mixing implicit and explicit, they do not play well together. If u have to mix them set the timeout to 0 for implicit before using explicit. Afterwards switch it back.